# Particles in C++ using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, particles

I want to start a basic particle system in C++ using OpenGL. I wrote an algorithm for that but I don't understand how to start it.

The problem I am facing is I can print the positions and velocity updates but I don't know how to show it visually using OpenGL.

Comment: Have you tried drawing quad in each position for all the particles?

Comment: use point sprites: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=770639&seqNum=7

Answer (score 4):

I hope you are trying out something on the lines of what is below:

- Have a structure(C++ struct or a class) to denote a Particle. The structure contains:

  - Particle location (x,y,z)
  - Particle velocity (Vx, Vy, Vz)
  - Particle acceleration (Ax, Ay,Az)  //something you *might* need too..
  - paint function to do the painting of the particle.
- Have an array of this structure. Initialise velocity, position, and acceleration as needed.
- In a separate thread (or in the repaint event, for starting up) do the following:

  - For every particle (element in the array) do:

    - particle[index].velocityX += particle[index].accelerationX
    - particle[index].velocityY += particle[index].accelerationY
    - particle[index].velocityZ += particle[index].accelerationZ
    - particle[index].locationX += particle[index].velocityX
    - particle[index].locationY += particle[index].velocityY
    - particle[index].locationZ += particle[index].velocityZ

    //translate to the location and paint..

    - Use glTranslated(particle[index].locationX, particle[index].locationY, particle[index].locationZ)

Comment: Hi guys, Can anyone give me example of basic particle system using openGL, or any link...

Comment: Umm, the bullets I have put down above, is pretty much sufficient to implement a basic particle system, IMO. Show us what you have tried, may be we can help. In case you need a code to start you up, google for it; I am sure you will end up with 1000s of it. :)